# Converting a list to string with prefix and suffix

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
myist = ['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

and I want to execute something via os.system() where multiple files are used in one line:

```
cat file0.txt file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > result.txt
```

but I'm not sure how to add a suffix when joining the list. This:

```
os.system("cat file" + ' file'.join(mylist) +".txt > result.txt" )
```

will give me:

```
cat file0 file1 file2 file3.txt > result.txt
```

but what I want is this:

```
cat file0.txt file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > result.txt
```

So what I'm searching for is something like `'prefix'.join(mylist).'suffix'`.
How can I do this without using for loops?

Comment: Use list comprehension

Comment: I don't want to use loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add the suffix to the start of the string:

```
os.system("cat file" + '.txt file'.join(mylist) +".txt > result.txt")
```

Or you could use string formatting with the map function:

```
os.system("cat " + ' '.join(map('file{0}.txt'.format, mylist)) + " > result.txt")
```

Comment: That did it... Thanks didn't thought about that

Answer (score 4):

Using a generator expression:

```
print  "cat " + " ".join("file%d.txt" % int(d) for d in mylist) + " > result.txt"
```

Comment: this is not a list comprehension

Comment: Didn't even know the difference, or rather the strict distinction, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case you every want to use it for more than 4 items

```
os.system('cat %s > result.txt'%(' '.join("file%i.txt"%i for i in xrange(0,4))))
```

you could also do:

```
mylist = ['0','1','2','3']
os.system('cat %s > result.txt'%(' '.join("file%s.txt"%i for i in mylist)))
```

but that's less fun.